# Detect XML 'schema' in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB to unmarshal an XML message (string) to a POJO.  Now it is possible to receive different kinds of messages.  Each kind of message has a different structure and maps to a different POJO.

e.g. PaymentRequest contains an amount and currency, PrintRequest contains a text and a logo

```
<PaymentRequest>
  <amount>1.0</amount>
  <currency>EUR</currency>
</PaymentRequest>

<PrintRequest>
  <text>Hello world!</text>
  <logo>stackoverflow.png</logo>
</PrintRequest>
```

What is the best way or best practice to identify which kind of message I have received?

- Should I add something to the message to make it easier to identify the string?  If so, what should I add (schema, namespace, ...)?
- Should I create a 'message' POJO which is a union of all different XML messages kinds I can receive?
- ...

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: if its being unmarshalled to a POJO, why not use a "null check" in code to get your things done.??

Comment: @SujeeshSValath I think the point here is that he isn't sure which POJO to unmarshall it to.

Comment: @EvanKnowles, if we have used xsd to generate JAXBs, and properly configured, xml nodes will be automatically unmarshalled right. I guess he is not generating Jaxbs from xsd here.

Comment: He has multiple XSDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just unmarshal and then check the type of the unmarshalled message?

You may need to construct a `JAXBContext` with several packages for this to work. Something like:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo.payment:com.acme.foo.print");
```

The context must know the elements you (potentially) want to unmarshal.

Next, in you schemas you may also use [substitution groups](http://www.xfront.com/ElementHierarchy.html) in your schema. Since both `PrintRequest` and `PaymentRequest`s are requests, you may want to define an abstract element for them:

```
<xs:element name="AbstractRequest" type="base:AbstractRequestType" abstract="true"/>
```

Then your `PrintRequest` and `PaymentRequest` may substitute this element:

```
<xs:element name="PaymentRequest" type="payment:PaymentRequestType" substititionGroup="base:AbstractRequest"/>
```

In your request/response schema you can use the `AbstractRequest` then which can be substituted by `PaymentRequest`. This will give you somewhat more type safety when unmarshalling. You'll know you'll get a `JAXBElement<? extends AbstractRequestType` and will only have to figure out, which of the request types that is. This can be done based on the `QName` of the `JAXBElement` or brute-force with `instanceof`. A finer approach would be to use a visitor pattern for this, but it's a bit more complicated to condigure.